# Cant find php72-pdo-pgsql / PostgreSQL driver for PHP using brew

Tags: php, postgresql, homebrew

I'm using PHP 7.2.3 installed using homebrew, and I want to install PostgreSQL driver for my PHP.

I tried to search the driver using homebrew search

```
jeremy@mbp ~ brew search php72-pdo-pgsql
==> Searching local taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
==> Searching blacklisted, migrated and deleted formulae...
No formula found for "php72-pdo-pgsql".
Closed pull requests:
enchant 2.2.0 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/21807)
Add PHP 7.2.0-alpha.1 core formula (php72) (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/pull/4211)
```

I tried brew update && brew upgrade but I still can't find the PostgreSQL driver for my version of PHP.

Also, I tried to search only with *brew search pgsql*, but none of the results is for my PHP version.

Here's my brew tap results

```
jeremy@mbp ~ brew tap
caskroom/cask
heroku/brew
homebrew/core
homebrew/dupes
homebrew/php
homebrew/services
```

And my brew version

```
jeremy@mbp ~ brew -v
Homebrew 1.5.10
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision c3a9a; last commit 2018-03-17)
```

Comment: verify your brew installation. On my box, if i `brew search php72` i do find this entry in the search `homebrew/php/php72-pdo-pgsql`, in local taps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since php72 that is included in the package. So if you do now 
`brew install php` you will get that included. Reference: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/commit/8771c68f3ddfee62d9e97177449010c2968f91d1#commitcomment-27883803